# How to encode decode string in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to encode string or any primitives values in `Thymeleaf` and decode same on server, mostly path variable or in hidden fields. Actually i want this due to security reasons.

**Effort**

```
<a th:href="@{/administrator/{id}edit/(id=${data.id})}" class="instructionbt">Edit</a>
```

This is a simple link to edit data and can be see in url something like this:

```
localhost:8080/testapp/administrator/1/edit
```

but i want something like

```
localhost:8080/testapp/administrator/$Htf1w==/edit
```

Now can replace 1 by 2, 3 even any number and can edit any data. I want that 1 (the id field) must be encode, so that id will be hard to guess and a normal user will not edit url directly.

I have search a lot on internet, but i did not found any clue. I know i can use `Base64Utils` or any similar class to achieve, but question is how to do in `Thymeleaf.`

Please friends help me. I am stuck in my project and i am having very less time.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is your input and your desired output?
Did you try th:text instead of th:href?

Comment: Ok, Let me add more input into my question.

Answer (score 1):

A normal user will not edit the URL anyway. A user that is not "normal" will never be stopped by Base64. That is for sure and that is why you won't find anything on the Internet. You need to protect the resource server side - e.g. check if number 1 belongs to the current user and he can edit it.

Skipping these checks is a very common security bug and is part of the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) list. It is [A4-Insecure Direct Object References](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References). Please read more about this vulnerability and how to prevent it. In short:

*Each use of a direct object reference from an untrusted source must include an access control check to ensure the user is authorized for the requested object.*

Comment: I know that we cannot stop a user who is not normal. But i just to add this for normal security. Just an administrator just forgot to logout or lock the system and any user came and found open that application. That user can harm the system. To avoid such situation i want to add this feature.

Comment: So the normal user comes and finds the the application open? Can he just click around without touching the URL-s? This sounds much more convenient for me. :-) If I leave open my gmail and you find it what would you do if you want to harm my account - would you play with fake URL-s? Don't try to handle these situations - it will not make your system more secure - it will just make it complicated. Setting a shorter session expiration time is the solution that people use for this scenario.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let me think and talk to my managers. But if they want then what could be the solutions.